# Restrictions to prove quasiconcavity utility function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the utility function given as $$u(x)=x_1+x_2^\gamma.$$ The answer says that for a utility function to exhibit strict quasi-concavity, $\gamma$ needs to be between $0$ and $1$; but I don't understand why this is true. I know strict quasi-concavity means that if $f(x)\ge f(x′)$, then $f((1−\lambda)x+\lambda x′)>f(x′$) but I don't know how this can be shown in this example...

Comment: I suspect there could be some miscommunication, can you use mathjax? surround mathy object with the dollar sign. Use \gamma and surround it with the dollar signs to produce $\gamma$. Use underscore for subscript and ^ for superscript.

Comment: Thanks @SiongThyeGoh, made the edits..

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh- do you know anyone who knows the answer?

Comment: I think we ahve to make the question clearer. May I know what is the domain of the function?

Comment: No range, just need to prove quasi concavity --- I did some research I need to show that this function is convex to prove quasiconcavity? @SiongThyeGoh

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the bordered Hessian?
$$ \bar{H} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & \gamma x_2^{\gamma-1} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \gamma x_2^{\gamma-1} & 0 & \gamma(\gamma-1)x_2^{\gamma-2} \end{bmatrix} $$

For this function to be quasiconcave, the determinant must be positive. Check the $\gamma$ that makes so.